# Reading in a binary grid file in Fortran 90

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, binaryfiles

I'm having issues when trying to read in a binary file I've previously written into another program.  I have been able to open it and read it to an array with out compilation errors, however, the array is not populated (all 0's).  Any suggestions or thoughts would be great.  Here is the open/read statement I'm using:

```
       allocate(dummy(imax,jmax))
       open(unit=io, file=trim(input), form='binary', access='stream', &
            iostat=ioer, status='old', action='READWRITE')

       if(ioer/=0) then
        print*, 'Cannot open file'
       else
        print*,'success opening file'
       end if

       read(unit=io, fmt=*, iostat=ioer) dummy
       j=0
       k=0
       size: do j=1, imax
           do k=1, jmax
             if(dummy(j,k) > 0.) print*,dummy(j,k)
           end do
       end do size
```

Please let me know if you need more info.

Here is how the file is originally written:

```
    out_file = trim(output_dir)//'SEVIRI_FRP_.08deg_'//trim(season)//'.bin'

    print*, out_file
    print*, i_max,' i_max,',j_max,' j_max'

   open (io, file = out_file, access = 'direct', status = 'replace', recl = i_max*j_max*4)

   write(io, rec = 1) sev_frp
   write(io, rec = 2) count_sev_frp
   write(io, rec = 3) sum_sev_frp

   check: do n=1, i_max
     inna: do m=1, j_max

       !if (sev_frp(n,m) > 0) print*, count_sev_frp(n,m)

     end do inna
   end do check

   print*,'n-',n,'m-',m
   close(io)
```

Comment: Why don't you check the value of `ioer` after the read?

Comment: Good call, ioer printed 'cannot open file'

Comment: Does you file exists? print the value of `input` variable and check if it really points to your file

Comment: Francescalus, do you have a suggestion on my read statement?  I have tried several different ways and get compilation errors.

Comment: I actually print out input right above this block and it does print to the file.  I've also opened the binary file in GrADS to make sure the data has been written and it displays correctly.

Comment: To give suggestions about reading, we need the `write` statement that you used to save the file. But to begin, you can read only if you open successfully. In your case the opening is failing.

Comment: Ok, I added the write statement above.  Then open statement worked, but following the open, the read statement fails.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to supply a format when reading in binary. Try `read(unit=io, iostat=ioer) dummy`.

Comment: Ok @Ross, it worked? (I think).  No compilation errors plus `dummy` is now populated with actual values.  But, `ioer` for `read(unit=io, iostat=ioer)` prints as cannot open?

Comment: Thanks for your help francescalus, innoSPG, and Ross!

Comment: I would usually not specify `iostat` at all while debugging code.  That way you get a (usually) intelligable system generated error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the `form` takes two possible values as far as I know: `"FORMATTED"` or `"UNFORMATTED"`.

Second, to read, you should use a `open` that is symmetric to the `open` statement that you used to write the file, Unless you know exactely what you are doing. I suggest that for reading, you open with:

```
open(unit=io, file=trim(input), access='direct', &
        iostat=ioer, status='old', action='READ', recl = i_max*j_max*4)
```

That corresponds to the open statement that you used to save the file.

Comment: `form=binary` is an obsolete, popular, extension.  The read, being direct, will also need changing.

Comment: @francescalus do you know which standard introduced `'binary'` as `form` in the open statement? I recently read the fortran 2008 draft for the `open` statement and I do not remember seing it.

Comment: @innoSPG extensions, by definition, are not part of the standard.

Comment: It's not standard, but ifort for one has it.

Comment: @francescalus I changed my `open` statement to match the `write` statement as you suggested. No compilation error but the array `dummy` is once again 0's.  I had originally tried `'direct'` access but I included `form='unformatted'` and I received compilation errors.

Comment: I don't understand how if the `open` statement is working the `read` statement is not.  There isn't much to it.  I thought maybe there was something wrong with the file, but I can open/view it in GrADS and the values are within limits of what is stored in the array.

Comment: @Trish, more importantly, you need to supply the record while reading unless you know what you are doing again. `read(unit=io, rec=1, iostat=ioer) dummy`

Comment: @innoSPG, Yes!  I now have success reading in.  I am definitely still a beginner to Fortran, which is why I'm very glad there is a forum like this.  Sometimes books and google just don't work.

Comment: @Trish, you are right, nothing can replace interactive forum like this one where you meet a huge community interacting almost real time. DO not forget to accept the answer if it was useful to solve the problem.

Comment: Note you *should* be able to perfectly well use *streams* to read a file written with *direct* access.

Comment: @agentp, good point. With my thinking, I always stick with the minimum that solve my problems.

Answer (score 2):

As [innoSPG says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32530884), you have a mismatch in the way the file is written and how it is read.

An external file may be connected with one of three access methods: sequential; direct; stream.  Further, a connection may be formatted or unformatted.

When the file is opened for writing it uses the direct access method with unformatted records.  The records are unformatted because this is the default (in the abscence of the `form=` specifier).

When you open the file for reading you use the non-standard extension of `form="binary"` and stream access.  There is possibly nothing wrong with this, but it does require care.

However, with the `read` statements you are using formatted (list-directed) input.  This will not be allowed.

The way suggested in the previous answer, of using a similar access method and record length will require a further change to the code.  [You'll also need to set the value of the record length somehow.]

Not only will you need to remove the format, to match the unformatted records written, but you'll want to use the `rec=` specifier to access the records of the file.

Finally, if you are using the `iostat=` specifier you really should check the resulting value.